# Avoid retrieving duplicates item (MYSQLi/PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysqli

As shown in the picture below, there is a subcategory with duplicates items in it, and the reason being is as follow:

It looks at the course title and sees which sub category is associate with it and populates that. The issue lies in that if you have 10 courses with similar course title and that have the same subcategory, that subcategory will be displayed multiple times. Hence, what I want to do is the following:

Have an if statements that stipulates that the subcategory name is already populated, than there is no need to populate it again. Below is how the subcategory is generated:

```
          $search_query = $_GET['user_query'];

$get_cats = "select * from courses where (course_title like '%$search_query%' )  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 5";

    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

    while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $crs_sub1 = $row_cats['course_subc1'];
                $crs_sub2 = $row_cats['course_subc2'];
                        $crs_sub3 = $row_cats['course_subc3'];

        $crs_sub4 = $row_cats['course_subc4'];

        $crs_sub5 = $row_cats['course_subc5'];




        echo "<a href='searchPage.php?user_query=$crs_sub1' id='liSpacing'><label id='labelSearch'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='value'>&nbsp;$crs_sub1</label></a> <br />";



    }
```

Thanks in advance

[image]

**Update**

Original:

```
 $get_cats = "select * from courses where (course_title like '%$search_query%' )  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 5";
```

Updated:

```
  $get_cats = "select distinct course_title from courses where (course_title like '%$search_query%' )  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 5";
```

with updated, I receive the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: course_subc1 in 

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc2 in 

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc3 in 

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc4 in 

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc5 in 


Notice: Undefined index: course_subc1 in

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc2 in 

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc3 in 

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc4 in 
Notice: Undefined index: course_subc5 in 


Notice: Undefined index: course_subc1 in 

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc2 in 

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc3 in 

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc4 in 

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc5 in 

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc1 in 

Notice: Undefined index: course_subc2 in 
Notice: Undefined index: course_subc3 in 
Notice: Undefined index: course_subc4 in 
Notice: Undefined index: course_subc5 in 
Notice: Undefined index: course_subc1 in 
Notice: Undefined index: course_subc2 in 
Notice: Undefined index: course_subc3 in
Notice: Undefined index: course_subc4 in 
Notice: Undefined index: course_subc5 in
```

Below are the lines of error:

```
 $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

            while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
                $crs_sub1 = $row_cats['course_subc1'];
                        $crs_sub2 = $row_cats['course_subc2'];
                                $crs_sub3 = $row_cats['course_subc3'];

                $crs_sub4 = $row_cats['course_subc4'];

                $crs_sub5 = $row_cats['course_subc5'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First things first.**

To fix your query (and prevent the Undefined index errors) you need to do this:

```
$get_cats = "select distinct course_title, course_subc1, course_subc2,
course_subc3, course_subc4, course_subc5 from courses where 
(course_title like '%$search_query%' )  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE()
LIMIT 5";
```

**Big But**

You are requesting 4 fields that you dont use: course_subc2, course_subc3, course_subc4 and course_subc5. Besides, if those are categories (they walk and talk like categories) you have a big normalization problem there. You should have a categories table and establish a proper relationship among courses and categories.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It seems like even with distinct the problem persist, and where duplicate courses are shown. At this point it is only echoing  $crs_sub1 where because 5 courses have the same subcategory title that is displayed.

Comment: it did fix my undefined index errors and i appreciate

Comment: To solve your problem you need to use the right aproach. If you do what i suggest in the Big But section (normalize using a categories table and establish a proper relatioship between courses and categories) you can easily do something like this (which actually works in my tables): SELECT DISTINCT medios_feeds_categorias.nombre_es, medios_feeds.nombre
FROM medios_feeds_categorias INNER JOIN medios_feeds ON medios_feeds.id_categoria = medios_feeds_categorias.id_objeto

Comment: oh i see. so there is no work around my case? I agree your approach is proper but there is a reasoning behind mine.

Comment: You can use the distinct keyword on the course_subc1: select distinct course_subc1, course_title, course_subc2, ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what your table structure is but we'll say that the name of the field is 'course_title'

```
$sql = "select distinct course_title from courses where (course_title like '%$search_query%' )  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've added an update under my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to SELECT DISTINCT to stop the duplication. Can't write the revised query because you did not supply any information about the table structure. Learn to supply the data needed for your questions and you will get better answers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've added an update under my initial post.